# how to colour a text line in beamer after it appeared?

Tags: beamer, color

I have three items, and I want to highlight the first one changing its colour. But I want to do this **after** the three items are seen. Can I do that?

It may be something like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\pause
\item Second item
\pause
\item Third item
\pause
*And here somehow the first item gets blue*
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added an example on the second item to show that it works for other commands too like putting in bold or italic, `<3->` means the effect (text formatting in this case **bold**) is active on the third slide, and remains after.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textcolor<4>{blue}{First item}
\pause
\item \textbf<3->{Second item}
\pause
\item Third item
\pause
*And here somehow the first item gets blue*
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```